# How to process Json with extra tags using scala and Gson

Tags: json, scala, gson

I have a Json format that usually comes with below schema:

case class Sensor(field1: String, field2: Long, field3: Double)

{"field1":"A","field2":"B","field3":"C"}

But many time Json is appended with more tags e.g.

{"field1":"A","field2":"B","field3":"C" ,"field4":"D"}

How do I handle such json messages using Gson, currently my code
is ignoring new fields and processing the messages which is correct but I want to log such json messages.

```
gson.fromJson(jsonStr, classOf[Sensor])
```

Comment: So your are currently successfully parsing the source and you want to just log the cases where you got more than the fields you were expecting?

Comment: Yes,currently it is ignoring new fields which is fine right now I want some kind of identifier that will help me with the filter json with extra fields

Comment: You want to capture the additional fields in the case class instances?

Comment: No I dont want to change my case class. May be some info from gson object which tells about the extra field will help.

Comment: Well, I got a workaround on this .. I know my json has 3 fields I using below code log json messages having more than 3 fields..(gson.fromJson(jsonStr, classOf[java.util.Map[String, String]]).size > 4) {
                  listExtraTagJson = listExtraTagJson.::(jsonStr)
                  logger.info("============= EXTRA TAG JSON ======== --> " + jsonStr)
                }